# Here is a simple java code giving an error may i know why so

Tags: java

```
interface Test {
    Object print();
}

class Test1 implements Test {
    public Object print() {
        System.out.print("print interface");
        return new Test1();
    }
}

public class E {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 t1 = new Test1();
        Test1 t2 = t1.print();
    }
}
```

Here print method is implemented in Test1 class a new test1 object t1 is created and using this object print method is called that returns the object of test1 class but i dont understand why it is giving compilation error

```
incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Test1
    Test1 t2=t1.print();
```

Comment: what is the error? are we supposed to guess it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this line,

```
Test1 t2 = t1.print();//wrong code
```

You have to explicitly typecast in this situation.

```
Test1 t2 = (Test1)t1.print();//correct code
```

You have to explicitly typecast in case of narrowing conversion(Parent class--->child class)
Your compiler automatically typecasts in widening conversions(Child class--->Parent class).

Comment: t2 is of Test1 and is a child class of Test interface when calling a method of Test1 it returns an object of type Test1 then why do i have to type cast can you be more clear

Comment: public Object print()
This method returns "Object" type(Object is super class of all other classes in java)
if you want your method to return object of type Test1 declaration should be as follows:
public Test1 print()

Comment: **print() method internally return Test1 object which is converted to "Object" class object (as you defined your code that way)**

Answer (score 1):

The `print()` method's return type is `Object`, not `Test1`. Since the compiler won't know that your are in fact returning an instance of `Test1`, it throws the error.

Either change the return type of `print()` to `Test` and type of `t2` to `Test`, or change the type of `t2` to `Object`.

Comment: I think you mean `Test1` not `Test`

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't actually. The interface shouldn't have any knowledge of its implementing classes and therefore the return type of `print()` shouldn't be `Test1`.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a statically checked language and it will give you a compile error if it cannot determine at compile time that your code is correct.

```
Test1 t2=t1.print();
```

is the same as

```
Object tmp = t1.print();
Test1 t2 = tmp; // this is a compiler error as it doesn't know the Object is a Test1
```

How you happen to use it doesn't mean it is no longer a compile error in this case.

A better alternative is to use a covariant return type.

```
public Test1 print() {
    System.out.print("print interface");
    return new Test1();
}
```

Note: that `Test1.print` has a more specific return type and makes it clear that it will be a `Test1`

---

BTW You can turn this into a runtime issue by using generics

```
interface Test {
    <T> T print(); 
}
class Test1 implements Test {
    public <T> T print() {
        System.out.print("print interface");
        return (T) new Test1();// you get a warning here but it compiles
   }
}
public class E {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test1 t1 = new Test1();
       Test1 t2 = t1.print(); // the compiler assumes the right type will be returned
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to turn this compile-time error into a runtime error?

Comment: @SamTebbs33 because you assume that at run time it will be right as it is in this case, you have to have a way to tell the compiler it will be fine for things the compiler cannot check for.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 Using a covariant return type is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @PeterLawrey's "BTW" just adds unnecessary confusion by the adding the possibility of failing at runtime.

If you want to be able to return the implementing type from the `Test.print` method, you can define a type variable *on the interface*, not on the method:

```
interface Test<T> {
  T print();
}

class Test1 implements Test<Test1> {
  @Override public Test1 print() {
    // ...
    return new Test1();
  }
}
```

Now, provided you don't use raw types or other things to break generics, you don't get any warnings, and you don't get any potential runtime failures.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast it, with this:

```
Test1 t2 = (Test1)t1.print();
```